# Correlated subquery in MySql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database, correlated-subquery

This is the most common example I find on internet when I look for "Correlated Subqueries" :

```
 SELECT employee_number, name
   FROM employees emp
   WHERE salary > (
     SELECT AVG(salary)
       FROM employees
       WHERE department = emp.department)
```

But My question is: In this syntax, (and in the others similar Correlated Subqueries) which is the "function" of the last line of the subquery -> `WHERE department = emp.department)` ?

I mean, what does MySql do when this line is executed ? It is the logic behind this syntax that is unclear to me.

I tried to execute only the subquery, in order to see/understand what is the output given but it gives me error. How can I understand the output of the inner query ?

My aim is to understand clearly the logic behind this syntax, so that I can understand when to use it. If it is too complex, is there a sort of rule to understand when to use it? In front of which problem do you say: "Ok, I must use a correlated subquery (with the syntax of my example)"?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, lets rewrite the query to use aliases for all tables and qualify all columns. Things will get a lot clearer by that:

```
SELECT e1.employee_number,
       e1.name
       FROM employees e1
            WHERE e1.salary > (SELECT avg(e2.salary)
                                      FROM employees e2
                                      WHERE e2.department = e1.department);
```

(And I recommend you make a habit of that. Either alias and qualify everything or nothing. A mix of both is just a mess.)

Now for your question:

For a subquery to be *correlated* it needs to be somehow "connected" to the outer query, otherwise it wasn't correlated. And that is what the `WHERE` clause in the subquery does.

As you can see, we got two instances of `employees` in the query as a whole, aliased `e1` and `e2`. (It might have been easier to understand, if you got an example that used two different tables...)

For each row of `e1` the subquery gets the average `salary` from `e2` where the rows of `e2` have the same `department` as the currently processed row from `e2`. (At least that's what happens *logically* -- what is *physically*  executed might take some shortcuts here and there but that's not important to understand the *meaning* of the query.) That average `salary` of the shared `department` is then compared to the `salary` of the row of `e1` with `>`.

The subquery cannot be executed on its own because it is correlated. Therefore, if you take it out of the context of the whole query, there's no `department` to compare to, as there is no other instance `e1` anymore. Hence it fails.

Comment: So, it is first executed the subquery, then when mysql encounters the "WHERE" clause, also the outer query is executed? Or it is a contemporary process?

Answer (score 1):

A query describes the result set, not the execution plan -- the optimizer figures that out.

Your query is a correlated subquery.  The first thing is to qualify all the column references so it is really clear which columns are which:

```
SELECT e.employee_number, e.name
FROM employees e
WHERE e.salary > (SELECT AVG(e2.salary)
                  FROM employees e2
                  WHERE e2.department = e.department
------------------------^ correlation clause
                 );
```

What is this doing?  Conceptually, the engine loops through each row of the `employees` table.  For each row, it then compares the salary to the average of all salaries in the same department -- that is what the correlation clause does.

This describes the result set that is produced.  The actual execution plan might be different from what is described above.